# feature.getId() returns null when loaded using ge.parseKml()

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

Using following code :

```
    var kmlPlacemark = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlPlacemark);
```

it does not seem to be possible to retrieve the placemarks' Id traversing the features collection like this :

```
    var features = ge.getGlobe().getFeatures().getChildNodes();

    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < features.getLength(); i++) {

            var aFeatureToRemove = features.item(i);
            alert (aFeatureToRemove.getId();
          }
         }
```

This always returns null, eventough the kmlString contains

```
     <placemark id="testId">
```

Is this supposed to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it :

Instead of

> aFeatureToRemove.getId()

had to use

> aFeatureToRemove.getFeatures().getFirstChild().getId()

Thanks for considering to help !